# IE7 compatibility error with div container with 4 divs inside

Tags: css, css-float, html

Basically this is my issue, I have a container with 4 divs inside, in firefox it works just fine and also in IE8 but ..it shows the compatibility view all the time, if I click on it, it moves the 4 divs out of the container, making the site looks terrible.
btw, the 4 divs are just behind the menu but on another "content" div. (I need it that way...)

This is my code.

```
<style type="text/css">
body{
    margin-top:2px; 
}

#main_frame{
     width:1024px;
     height:550px;
     position:relative;
     margin:0 auto;
     padding:0px;
     float:center;
     text-align:center;
     background:black;
}
#logo{
    width:275px;
    height:75px;
    background-image:url(images/logo.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0px;
         float:left;
    }
#top_center{
    width:474px;
    height:75px;
    position: relative;
    top:0px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0px;
    background-color:green;
    float:left;
        filter:alpha(opacity=50);
        -moz-opacity:0.5;
        -khtml-opacity: 0.5;
        opacity: 0.5;


    }
#top_right{
    width:275px;
    height:75px;
    position: relative;
    top:0px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0px;
    background-color:red;
    float:left;

    }
#main_menu{
    width:1024px;
    height:25px;
    float:none;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0px;
    background-color: #FF0;

          }
#content_frame{
    height:400px;
    width:1024px;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0px;    
}
/* HERE THEY ARE */

#tag1{
    height:375px;
    width:256px;
    position:  absolute;
    float:left;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0px;
    background-color:#900;
}
#tag2{
    height:375px;
    width:256px;
    position:absolute;
        float:left;
    margin-left:256px;
    padding:0px;
    background-color: #930;
}
#tag3{
    height:375px;
    width:256px;
        position:absolute;
    float:left;
    margin-left:512px;
    padding:0px;
    background-color: #960;
}
#tag4{
    height:375px;
    width:256px;
    display: inherit;
    position:absolute;
    float:left;
    margin-left:768px;
    padding:0px;
    background-color:#990;
}
</style>
```

... some code removed...

```
<body>
 <div id="main_frame">

         <div id="tag1"></div>
         <div id="tag2"></div>
         <div id="tag3"></div>
         <div id="tag4"></div>
  <div id="logo"></div>
  <div id="top_center"></div>
  <div id="top_right"></div>
  <div id="main_menu"></div>
  <div id="content_frame">
```

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Thanks guys,

Marco,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A link to a live page is almost *required* to tell you how to definitively fix this.

At the moment, it's too much work to try and recreate the problem (too many unknown variables).

Does your page have a [doctype](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/)?

When I see this:

> but ..it shows the compatibility view
>   all the time

It suggests that your page is being coerced into IE7 mode.

The usual cause is having this line in your page:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

The *probable* correct thing to do is remove this line, and fix your site to work in IE8.

Another thing you didn't specify is how well this works in other browsers such as Firefox, Chrome - and whether you care about this.

If this answer doesn't help you enough, post a link to your live page.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment.

Look, this is my doctype declaration.

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

I don't have any additional meta-tag with info in the code, the live site is just right here ... http://securebitcr.com/test/index.php so you can take a look at it.

Thanks for the help.
Marco,

Comment: My answer was a bit off base I see - I guessed the wrong way round. Your page *works* in IE8, but is broken in IE7.

Comment: By default!!! it works, but shows that little icon notifying the "compatibility" view..., when you click on it, the page is.... destroyed!
Sorry if I was not clear enough, maybe my question should be, how to get rid of that icon on IE8.
@thirtydot

Comment: That icon makes IE8 behave as if it's IE7. I thought I fixed it to work in IE7.. You *could* add a meta tag: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />` which will "get rid of that icon on IE8" - however, doing that won't stop your site looking wrong for IE7 users.

Comment: Thanks for all the help on this, now I understood the reason of that weird and ugly icon!.. well, another reason to hate IE, because it works just fine even in opera-mini!

Well, let's restructure that!, thanks, I really appreciate your time and help.
@thirtydot

Answer (score 0):

To fix your problem, follow these steps:

- Move `<div id="tag1"></div>`, `<div id="tag2"></div>`, `<div id="tag3"></div>`, `<div id="tag4"></div>` to *inside* `<div id="content_frame"></div>`, like this:

  ```
  <div id="main_frame">

      <div id="logo"></div>
      <div id="top_center"></div>
      <div id="top_right"></div>
      <div id="main_menu"></div>

      <div id="content_frame">
          <div id="tag1"></div>
          <div id="tag2"></div>
          <div id="tag3"></div>
          <div id="tag4"></div>
      </div>

  </div>
  ```
- Then, from those four tag `divs`, remove the `margin` and `position: absolute` rules.

I've tested that this fixes it to work in IE7, IE8, Firefox.

As an aside, after my fix I don't think *any* of your elements requires the `position: relative` rule any longer.

Comment: Yep.. It works but not as I need.
The point is, that I need to have those 4 divs behind the logo area, the header div ..., because those will be independent images at the back.
So the structure is something like this.

LOGO ----- some content ------ phone and brief description
MENU--------
CONTENT------
FOOTER------
BUT.. the 4 divs in the background! ... You saw the original one... it works on firefox correctly, and even in IE8, but with the compatibility issue.
Maybe you have another idea, I'm still trying to make it work, thanks for your help!!!

@thirtydot